# ESXi 4.0 - cannot copy files

Tags: copy, vmware-esx

I am unable to copy files or make directories on my installation of VMWare ESXi 4.0. I have done so in the past (copied an iso onto a datastore). But something has changed and I have no idea what.

- I cannot copy using the datastore browser (get a dialog saying "Expected a PUT_FILE_DONE message. Got SESSION_COMPLETE").
- I cannot create a directory through datastore browser (get a dialog saying "Cannot complete file creation operation").
- When I ssh to the ESXi server I cannot create files or folders under /vmfs/volumes. But I can manipulate files elswhere (including /vmfs).

Here are the permissions for the directories (I am logged in as root).

```
    ~ # ls -lh /vmfs/volumes/
drwxr-xr-t    1 root     root         1.2k Sep  3 12:19 4a76f260-36b7eb85-c3b3-0024e8314929
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            8 Jan  1  1970 4a76f261-d6190a9e-3b89-0024e8314929
drwxr-xr-t    1 root     root         1.4k Sep 22 10:38 4a76f262-4ac21f0a-6bc1-0024e8314929
l---------    0 root     root         1.9k Jan  1  1970 Hypervisor1 -> c42ce27f-eb8d7f70-7f70-0e7a85e8edc4
l---------    0 root     root         1.9k Jan  1  1970 Hypervisor2 -> bbf1477b-4aec1d8c-caa5-5e8720bebd85
l---------    0 root     root         1.9k Jan  1  1970 Hypervisor3 -> efd8efe3-03bc1cbf-15e0-080efd9e7379
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            8 Jan  1  1970 bbf1477b-4aec1d8c-caa5-5e8720bebd85
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            8 Jan  1  1970 c42ce27f-eb8d7f70-7f70-0e7a85e8edc4
l---------    0 root     root         1.9k Jan  1  1970 datastore1 -> 4a76f260-36b7eb85-c3b3-0024e8314929
l---------    0 root     root         1.9k Jan  1  1970 datastore2 -> 4a76f262-4ac21f0a-6bc1-0024e8314929
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            8 Jan  1  1970 efd8efe3-03bc1cbf-15e0-080efd9e7379
```

~ # touch /vmfs/foo.txt
~ # touch /vmfs/volumes/foo.txt
touch: /vmfs/volumes/foo.txt: Operation not permitted

I've googled and found nothing helpful. Does anyone out there have an idea as to what is going on?

Thanks in Advance.

Pete.

Comment: Can you post a df and vdf output also?  It may be that vmfs/volumes is on another datastore and is mounted read only or has other problems...

Comment: Try: touch /vmfs/volumes/datastore1/foo.txt

Answer (score -1):

Dumb Question, but do you get the same error when going through the vsphere client? I have one instance where the vsphere client automatically fixed the mistaken permission setting on the ISO directory and was available to the device again correctly.

Comment: I couldn't get it work any which way. I wish something I did would fix the permissions.